# Debugging JSPs using STS and the bundled vFabric tc Server

Tags: jsp, debugging, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I have installed STS with the vFabric tc Server and am working on developing a web app using spring Roo. I'm able to set break points and debug through my controllers, but am running into what is probably a simple problem in the JSPs but when I set breakpoints in them they seem to be ignored.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to do this on STS. Not even sure if it's possible (if someones knows, I also want to know it!)

The only thing I can say about debugging JSPs is using firebug or similar for seeing if the HTML is displayed correctly, or checking javascript.

Comment: I've gotten so far as to be able to set a breakpoint in a tag implementation in Java and them walking up the stack to view the jsp and its variables, but I still can't set breakpoints or step through.